# Grub2 mutual dependency issue

Tags: grub2, dpkg, dependencies, deb, debug

For various reasons I am installing .deb dependencies for grub2 using `dpkg` directly (rather than `apt-get`).

```
root@ubuntu:/dl# dpkg -i grub-gfxpayload-lists_0.6_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package grub-gfxpayload-lists.
(Reading database ... 249808 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack grub-gfxpayload-lists_0.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking grub-gfxpayload-lists (0.6) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-gfxpayload-lists:
 grub-gfxpayload-lists depends on grub-pc (>= 1.99~20101210-1ubuntu2); however:
  Package grub-pc is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-gfxpayload-lists (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-gfxpayload-lists
```

By configure I assume it means install+configure, so I tried:

```
root@ubuntu:/dl# dpkg -i grub-pc_2.02~beta2-9_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 249818 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack grub-pc_2.02~beta2-9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking grub-pc (2.02~beta2-9) over (2.02~beta2-9) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-pc:
 grub-pc depends on grub2-common (= 2.02~beta2-9); however:
  Package grub2-common is not installed.
 grub-pc depends on grub-pc-bin (= 2.02~beta2-9); however:
  Package grub-pc-bin is not installed.
 grub-pc depends on grub-gfxpayload-lists; however:
  Package grub-gfxpayload-lists is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: try to install that .deb file through gdebi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work, and my GRUB is now fixed (was able to run `update-grub` from `chroot`ed mount on my live cd).

gdebi didn't work (same error), what did work was giving `dpkg` this argument:

```
--force-depends
```